# Docker container settings to mimic Linux Systemd service

Tags: performance, docker, systemd

This is a question relating to configuring Docker on Linux to ensure the best performance. I'm wondering what settings / command-line flags need to be passed to a `docker run` command to ensure that the container runs as closely as possible to its equivalent on `systemd` ?

Would this simply be `--privileged` and `--net host` ? How would these settings passed to a Docker container compare (in terms of performance) to the same service running on `systemd` ?

Thank you!

Comment: This would make little difference in terms of performance but you would loose a lot of isolation.

Comment: If running it under systemd is critical to you, running the process in a VM (with systemd, all of the supporting system daemons, and simulated hardware) might be a better match.  You shouldn't use either of the Docker options you suggest in normal operation.